# Increase varchar() size of all columns in a table?

Tags: mysql, alter

We can modify the varchar() size of a single column by :

```
ALTER TABLE *table* MODIFY *column name* VARCHAR(1000);
```

Is there a way to issue this command for all columns of a table?

Comment: How many columns does your table have? I wouldn't have thought that this is something that would require automation, I certainly wouldn't have thought that this would happen regularly - why not just do it manually? If you want to, I'm sure you could set up a stored procedure to do it and loop over the columns using an `EXPLAIN` query.

Comment: 25 columns. It's not a lot, but it could be tedious for larger tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can modify multiple columns in one ALTER statement:

```
ALTER TABLE *table* 
    MODIFY *columnname1* VARCHAR(1000), 
    MODIFY *columnname2* VARCHAR(1000), 
    MODIFY *columnname3* VARCHAR(1000),
    ...etc...;
```

There is no syntax for "modify all varchar columns" in one clause.

But you can *generate* the verbose query like above:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '` ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MODIFY COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME, '` VARCHAR(1000)')), ';') AS _alter
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME) = ('mydatabase', 'mytable')
  AND COLUMN_TYPE LIKE 'VARCHAR%'
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Save the output of that query and execute it as an SQL script.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Verbose query helped a lot to me, while migrating a lot of tables to utf8mb4 and decreasing varchar 255 to 191.